# MPLAB X freeze building using printf

Tags: build, pic, mplab

My setup is:

- MPLAB X IDE v3.40
- C30 compiler v3.31
- PIC24FJ128GA306

Mi problem comes when I try to use printf. I can print a string but not a variable.

This line is correctly bompiled:

```
printf("HI");
```

This line is not correctly builded:

```
unsigned int var;
var = 1; 
printf("%u", var);
```

The same code works perfectly with other PIC (PIC24FJ512GA606) and compiler (XC16).
In both project we are using printf from the same library stdio.h

The problem comes when I try to build the project. If i use "printf("%u", var);" and build it, the IDE hangs and I have to cancel the building process. After it I can't clean the project, the IDE shows me the next text:

```
rm: no se puede borrar build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/interrupts_remapped.o: Permission denied
rm: no se puede borrar build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/mult.o: Permission denied
rm: no se puede borrar build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_debug.o: Permission denied
rm: no se puede borrar build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_formatter.o: Permission denied
rm: no se puede borrar build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_HAL_axis_references.o: Permission denied
rm: no se puede borrar build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_internal_comms.o: Permission denied

CLEAN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 123ms)
```

If I go to the folder and try to delete manually, a message appears saying that I cant delete it because "pic30-elf-gcc.exe" is using it. I have to close the process and then y can clean and rebuild the project with "printf("Hi");"...

EDIT1: I can observe when I build the project that every files are compiled correctly. The problem comes with the linker... When I try to build the project it get hangs with the next line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\MPLAB C30\bin\pic30-gcc.exe"   -omf=elf -mcpu=24FJ128GA306  -o dist/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/sf-device.production.elf build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/DEE_Emulation/DEE_Emulation_16-bit_v2.2/DEE_Emulation_16-bit/DEE_Emulation_16-bit.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/DEE_Emulation/DEE_Emulation_16-bit_v2.2/DEE_Emulation_16-bit/Flash_Operations.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/RS485/SF_RS485.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/src/ADC_Handler/ADC_Handler.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/src/Event_Timer/osal_timers.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/src/PWM/PWM_Core_Handler.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/src/PWM/PWM_Func_Layer.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/src/PWM/PWM_Hal_Layer.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/HTS221.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/LISXDH.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/src/Tasks/LED_Status_Task.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/src/Tasks/System_Task_Handler.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/src/Tasks/Hum_Temp_Task.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/configuration_bits.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/main.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/system.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/traps.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/user.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_controller.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_solar_calculations.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_solar_calculations_utils.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_time.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_tracker.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_settings.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_protocol.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_io_manager.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_inverter.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/utils.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_main_loop.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_persistence.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_formatter_binary.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_GW_Common.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_tick.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/mult.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_internal_comms.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/interrupts_remapped.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_formatter.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_HAL_axis_references.o build/SF_Utility_v31_RS485/production/SF_debug.o        -legacy-libc -Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1,--heap=1024,-Map="prueba.map",-Tp24FJ128GA306.gld
```

Comment: Show the definition of var and a bit more code. The problem is certainly not that line alone, it just exhibits another problem.

Comment: This is obviously an IDE problem/bug and not related to the code as such. Perhaps it goes muppet if given a variadic function and invoking code completion, something like that?

Comment: It is a really large project and I can't show it... I edit with the definition of the var, anyway it works with the other compiler/PIC

Comment: Your IDE is pretty old! Maybe try to update to versin 5.45

Comment: Bad news, updating IDE doesn't work... It hangs when compiling finish and the linker starts working.

Comment: Your compiler (C30) is also a pretty outdated compiler no longer supported - how about using XC compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution. The problem was that my project had the legacy libraries actives... Uncheking that option in the project configuration it is running correctly now.